# Вставить байты в FileStream C#

Tags: c#, filestream

Всем доброго времени суток. Мне нужно вставить байты в поток, но дело в том, что если в потоке есть, допустим строка "123456789", то если я записываю в него строку "абв" со второго байта, получается "12абв6789", а мне нужно "12абв3456789". 
Есть ли способ вставить в поток байты?

```
public int WriteData(int offset, string data)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[data.Length];
                bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                fileStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: "если я записываю в него ... получается ... а мне нужно" - способ есть, Вы записываете неправильно. Что конкретно Вы делаете неправильно, сказать невозможно, пока не придет кто-нибудь, кто угадает, как выглядит Ваш код.

Comment: код добвил, поток перед вызовом функции открывается.

Comment: С одним потоком это сделать не получится. Заводите два - один читающий, другой пишущий.

Comment: Вставить в середину,  раздвинув другие данные - нельзя. Придется переписывать весь хвост после вставляемых байтов.

Comment: То есть создавать временный файл, писать в него хвост, и только после того, как даные вписаны - писать хвост из этого файла в основной поток?

Comment: Ну почему сразу "временный файл"? Вы же только что говорили о потоках. Почему нельзя создать временный поток?

Comment: Если файл небольшой, то его можно весь в память считать, а на его место записать те данные, что вам надо. Если файл большой или может вырасти до большого, что не влезет в память, тогда да, временный файл и чтение/запись с буфером

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моём случае я использовал вместо потока строку string. Файл не предполагается размером более 500Кб, поэтому пока годится. В случае если понадобятся изменения - скорее всего прибегну к помощи временного файла. Если кому интересно, вот код:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> writersData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public string WriteData(string cName, int offset, string data)
        {
            try
            {
                writersData[cName] = writersData[cName].Insert(offset, data);
                return OperationResult.success;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
public string RemoveData(string cName, int offset, int count)
        {
            try
            {
                writersData[cName] = writersData[cName].Remove(offset, count);
                return OperationResult.success;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
```

Всем спасибо!